# Possible to sell various content sets via a single in-app purchase slot?

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, ios11

If my application offers four content sets that can alter the appearance of the app, is it possible (in iOS 11) to have a single in-app purchase where the content set is specified, or would they have to be configured as four different in-app purchases?  They are all the same price, and the customer can purchase more than one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: I'd say it's programming related, since he asked about storekit in particular with the tag

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's docs (no changes for iOS 11):

> The SKMutablePayment class defines a request to the Apple App Store to process payment for additional functionality offered by your application. A payment encapsulates a **string that identifies a particular product** and the quantity of that item the user would like to purchase.

Comment: This is a good take on the design - I can sell multiple copies of the same purchase and then track which content set is selected in a way that is independent of StoreKit